# Installing Windows 10 onto an old PC

Tags: windows-10, boot, installation, windows-10-upgrade, windows-installation

I'm trying to upgrade an XP machine to Windows 10, but I cannot get it to boot from DVD or USB flash drive. I formatted the old HDD, and, with Windows 10 in, I just keep getting a "cannot boot from DVD" error 5, but when I put an XP disc in, it has no problem installing XP again.
With the USB, I get to "Searching for boot record from USB RMD-FDD..OK", and then it just stops there.

I followed the MS instructions to do both DVD and USB versions.
How can I determine what is going wrong, and fix it?

Comment: does the pc meet the minimum requirements for installing windows 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When installing Windows 7, CDBOOT error 5 appears: Cannot boot from CD; why?](http://superuser.com/questions/28123/when-installing-windows-7-cdboot-error-5-appears-cannot-boot-from-cd-why)

Comment: I've run the win 7 upgrade tool and says all ok.. basics are: 2.4G celeron 2Gb Ram AsRock mobo..

Comment: Possible duplicate? Tried the way shown on there using the imgburn.. still no joy now when i try booting with DVD i get: searching for boot record from CDROM..OK    CDBOOT: Couldn't find NTLDR.. then boots into the xp version already on the drive

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the installation process for W7 is not the same as W10 and the same solution may not work on W10.

Comment: That's what i was thinking Frank, but it seems everything for win 10 takes you to an answer for win 7 or 8.. so thought it was worth a go..

Comment: I would start with look for a BIOS update.  Chances are you never did one, and it probably needs it.

Comment: Are you sure your DVD drive can handle the disc type? Ex: DVD-R DL/Dual-Layer? Can you try it & Win10 disc with a newer PC?

Comment: you can download Img file from Microsoft official site and create a bootable USB from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download iso image file to in-place upgrade Windows

From official website, using media creation tool to download iso file, or just use this tool to create your USB bootable drive.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

One more thing, please remove all external drive and close security software during upgrade.

Comment: Maybe the PC does not meet the minimum requirements for windows 10

Comment: @Sam, that cannot interfere with the initial boot process.

Comment: It might be incompatibility of motherboard with the DVD boot sector used by Microsoft in Windows 10 installation DVD.

Comment: Origami, thanks for that, but tried all the microsoft routes i can understand..Also there are no external drives and as it's on a formatted HDD, there's no security software on it.

Comment: Sam, did all the tests with the online tool checker for win 7 and was ok. Mobo and DVD worked with XP.. But did read somewhere that the AS Rock mobo was a bit iffy. The PC is still waiting for me to sort it as it's my mums.

Comment: Just a thought.. It's an IDE HDD.. would that cause any problems as the mobo doesn't have sata ports?